# How is skype android app doing it?

Tags: android, android-layout

If you have seen the skype android app, then you may have noticed that when skype moves from one activity to another, the top bar remains in place while the rest of the page slides out and the new activity comes in.

So how are they doing it? I want to do something like that.

Comment: you should use view flipper, i think android market uses it, very cool effect

Comment: if you got the answer, please mark the correct one accepted

Comment: no. i am yet to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) can do what you wan't, and a lot more

Comment: fragments came only after 3.0. But this has been there even in 2.2.

Comment: The compatibility library allows fragments all the way back to 1.6

Comment: thanks for that. Checking out http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Answer (score 2):

In skype.. They are using `Tab Activity`...

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

[Android TabHost Tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1)

Also if you want to use a single title through out the applciation :

You can define a title_layout.xml... & include it in the top of all your layouts like

```
<include layout="@layout/title_header"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I want. Skype does not look like it has any tabs. Should we override something?

Comment: could u pls tell me...which skype  version ypu are checking .. or give me the skype android market link.. so that i can go throuh the screenshots & verify it

Comment: If you are using TabActivity .. go through the sample http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I am using Skype version 2.1.0.46

Comment: is that you need .. refer this pic http://www.bittu.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/skype-for-android.png

Comment: this is  wat ur asking right :  https://androidmarket.googleusercontent.com/android/market/com.skype.raider/ss-480-1-9

Comment: yes exactly this one. https://androidmarket.googleusercontent.com/android/market/com.skype.raider/ss-480-1-9

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5187/discussion-between-jennifer-and-sudarshan-bhat)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom view which will act as your Tab Bar.

After creating your custom tab bar use it in whatever activity as you want.

Check this for more info on custom views.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html